# Assistance with table in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got a table within my document that has decided to move right up to the top of a page and for some reason I am unable to move it. I tried the <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and all it does is move the table to a page below in exactly the same position. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to drag it around by the [image] that appears in the upper left corner of the table when you mouse over it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> creates a page break, so that's why it's moving it to the same place on the new page.

More info: [Position a table on a page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/position-a-table-on-a-page-HP005256739.aspx)

Comment: This sounds like it would suit better as a comment and less as an answer. I know you don't have enough reputation points to comment, but do keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I know, thanks. I'll try and make it more explicitly answery.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the table handle, right-click on the table, select "Table Properties", and make sure the text wrapping is set to "None".

[image]